# Alsa doesn't recognize soundcards but kernel does

Tags: arch-linux, audio, alsa, alsamixer

I've an issue with alsa which seems not to recognize my soundcards. Before I didn't have that issue...

```
    !!################################
    !!ALSA Information Script v 0.4.64
    !!################################

    !!Script ran on: Mon Jan  6 18:28:00 UTC 2020


    !!Linux Distribution
    !!------------------

    ID_LIKE=arch


    !!DMI Information
    !!---------------

    Manufacturer:      Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
    Product Name:      B450M DS3H
    Product Version:   Default string
    Firmware Version:  F41
    Board Vendor:      Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
    Board Name:        B450M DS3H-CF


    !!ACPI Device Status Information
    !!---------------

    /sys/bus/acpi/devices/AMDI0030:00/status     15
    /sys/bus/acpi/devices/AMDIF030:00/status     15
    /sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXTHERM:00/status     11
    /sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0103:00/status      15
    /sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0501:00/status      15
    /sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0A08:00/status      15
    /sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C01:00/status      15
    /sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C02:01/status      15
    /sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C02:03/status      15
    /sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0C:00/status      11
    /sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:00/status      11
    /sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:01/status      11
    /sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:02/status      11
    /sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:03/status      11
    /sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:04/status      11
    /sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:05/status      11
    /sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:06/status      11
    /sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:07/status      11
    /sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C14:01/status      11


    !!Kernel Information
    !!------------------

    Kernel release:    5.4.6-2-MANJARO
    Operating System:  GNU/Linux
    Architecture:      x86_64
    Processor:         unknown
    SMP Enabled:       Yes


    !!ALSA Version
    !!------------

    Driver version:     k5.4.6-2-MANJARO
    Library version:    1.2.1.2
    Utilities version:  1.2.1


    !!Loaded ALSA modules
    !!-------------------



    !!Sound Servers on this system
    !!----------------------------

    Pulseaudio:
          Installed - Yes (/usr/bin/pulseaudio)
          Running - Yes

    Jack:
          Installed - Yes (/usr/bin/jackd)
          Running - No


    !!Soundcards recognised by ALSA
    !!-----------------------------

    --- no soundcards ---


    !!PCI Soundcards installed in the system
    !!--------------------------------------

    07:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GP107GL High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
    09:00.3 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) HD Audio Controller


    !!Advanced information - PCI Vendor/Device/Subsystem ID's
    !!-------------------------------------------------------

    07:00.1 0403: 10de:0fb9 (rev a1)
        Subsystem: 10de:11c0
    --
    09:00.3 0403: 1022:1457
        Subsystem: 1458:a182


    !!Loaded sound module options
    !!---------------------------


    !!ALSA Device nodes
    !!-----------------

    crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  1 Jan  6 18:50 /dev/snd/seq
    crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 33 Jan  6 18:50 /dev/snd/timer


    !!Aplay/Arecord output
    !!--------------------

    APLAY

    aplay: device_list:272: no soundcards found...

    ARECORD

    arecord: device_list:272: no soundcards found...

    !!Amixer output
    !!-------------


    !!Alsactl output
    !!--------------

    --startcollapse--
    --endcollapse--


    !!All Loaded Modules
    !!------------------

    Module
    ccm
    fuse
    squashfs
    loop
    rtl8192ee
    btcoexist
    rtl_pci
    rtlwifi
    edac_mce_amd
    mac80211
    kvm_amd
    snd_intel_nhlt
    kvm
    snd_hda_codec
    irqbypass
    cfg80211
    r8169
    snd_hda_core
    crct10dif_pclmul
    crc32_pclmul
    snd_hwdep
    ghash_clmulni_intel
    realtek
    uinput
    mousedev
    rfkill
    snd_pcm
    joydev
    input_leds
    aesni_intel
    nvidia_drm
    wmi_bmof
    snd_timer
    nvidia_modeset
    snd
    crypto_simd
    ccp
    cryptd
    sp5100_tco
    glue_helper
    pcspkr
    soundcore
    i2c_piix4
    k10temp
    libarc4
    libphy
    rng_core
    drm_kms_helper
    wmi
    drm
    pinctrl_amd
    gpio_amdpt
    evdev
    mac_hid
    acpi_cpufreq
    agpgart
    syscopyarea
    sysfillrect
    sysimgblt
    fb_sys_fops
    nvidia
    ipmi_devintf
    ipmi_msghandler
    crypto_user
    ip_tables
    x_tables
    ext4
    crc32c_generic
    crc16
    mbcache
    jbd2
    hid_logitech_hidpp
    hid_logitech_dj
    hid_generic
    usbhid
    hid
    sd_mod
    ahci
    libahci
    libata
    crc32c_intel
    xhci_pci
    scsi_mod
    xhci_hcd


    !!ALSA/HDA dmesg
    !!--------------
```

```
    ➜  ~ alsactl init  
    alsactl: sysfs_init:48: sysfs path '/sys' is invalid

    alsactl: init:1759: No soundcards found...
    ➜  ~ alsamixer 
    le mixeur ne peut pas être ouvert: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
```

```
[redgl0w redgl0w]# rmmod snd-hda-intel; modprobe snd-hda-intel; dmesg | tail
rmmod: ERROR: Module snd_hda_intel is not currently loaded
modprobe: ERROR: Error running install command for snd_hda_intel
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'snd_hda_intel': Operation not permitted
[   57.223367] audit: type=1100 audit(1578342370.883:68): pid=2098 uid=1000 auid=1000 ses=2 subj==unconfined msg='op=PAM:authentication grantors=pam_unix,pam_permit acct="redgl0w" exe="/usr/bin/sudo" hostname=? addr=? terminal=/dev/pts/0 res=success'
[   57.223711] audit: type=1101 audit(1578342370.886:69): pid=2098 uid=1000 auid=1000 ses=2 subj==unconfined msg='op=PAM:accounting grantors=pam_unix,pam_permit,pam_time acct="redgl0w" exe="/usr/bin/sudo" hostname=? addr=? terminal=/dev/pts/0 res=success'
[   57.224131] audit: type=1110 audit(1578342370.886:70): pid=2098 uid=0 auid=1000 ses=2 subj==unconfined msg='op=PAM:setcred grantors=pam_unix,pam_permit acct="root" exe="/usr/bin/sudo" hostname=? addr=? terminal=/dev/pts/0 res=success'
[   57.229977] audit: type=1105 audit(1578342370.890:71): pid=2098 uid=0 auid=1000 ses=2 subj==unconfined msg='op=PAM:session_open grantors=pam_limits,pam_unix,pam_permit acct="root" exe="/usr/bin/sudo" hostname=? addr=? terminal=/dev/pts/0 res=success'
[   57.232712] audit: type=1106 audit(1578342370.893:72): pid=2098 uid=0 auid=1000 ses=2 subj==unconfined msg='op=PAM:session_close grantors=pam_limits,pam_unix,pam_permit acct="root" exe="/usr/bin/sudo" hostname=? addr=? terminal=/dev/pts/0 res=success'
[   57.232852] audit: type=1104 audit(1578342370.893:73): pid=2098 uid=0 auid=1000 ses=2 subj==unconfined msg='op=PAM:setcred grantors=pam_unix,pam_permit acct="root" exe="/usr/bin/sudo" hostname=? addr=? terminal=/dev/pts/0 res=success'
[   61.145820] audit: type=1101 audit(1578342374.806:74): pid=2107 uid=1000 auid=1000 ses=2 subj==unconfined msg='op=PAM:accounting grantors=pam_unix,pam_permit,pam_time acct="redgl0w" exe="/usr/bin/sudo" hostname=? addr=? terminal=/dev/pts/0 res=success'
[   61.146060] audit: type=1110 audit(1578342374.806:75): pid=2107 uid=0 auid=1000 ses=2 subj==unconfined msg='op=PAM:setcred grantors=pam_unix,pam_permit,pam_env acct="root" exe="/usr/bin/sudo" hostname=? addr=? terminal=/dev/pts/0 res=success'
[   61.151701] audit: type=1105 audit(1578342374.813:76): pid=2107 uid=0 auid=1000 ses=2 subj==unconfined msg='op=PAM:session_open grantors=pam_limits,pam_unix,pam_permit acct="root" exe="/usr/bin/sudo" hostname=? addr=? terminal=/dev/pts/0 res=success'
[   61.160687] audit: type=1100 audit(1578342374.823:77): pid=2108 uid=0 auid=1000 ses=2 subj==unconfined msg='op=PAM:authentication grantors=pam_rootok acct="root" exe="/usr/bin/su" hostname=redgl0w addr=? terminal=pts/0 res=success'
[redgl0w redgl0w]#
```

Thank you !

Comment: What is the output of `rmmod snd-hda-intel; modprobe snd-hda-intel; dmesg | tail` (as root)?

Comment: I added that in the message !

Comment: Please do this as root.

Comment: I ran it as root ?

Comment: Sorry, that `redgl0w` looks like a user name. But then why are you not allowed to load a kernel module?

Comment: That's my hostname...

Comment: Any sound-related entries in `/etc/modprobe.conf` or `/etc/modprobe.d/*`?

Comment: Yep, in modprobe.conf I've got `install snd_hda_intel /bin/false`
I removed the line, and it works well !
Thanks !

Comment: Please write an answer. And how did that line happen to go into there?

Comment: I don't why it appeared there : I checked my zsh history, i don't have any log related, and I tried to see in the things I installed if there was something related, but it seems not...

Answer (score 1):

I removed in my `modprobe.conf` the line about snd-intel

```
install snd_hda_intel /bin/false
```

This solved the problem.

Comment: Welcome to the site and congratulations on figuring out the problem. To make your answer more useful to others facing a similar problem, please add more explanation (e.g. which line exactly was the problem, with a copy of the offending line included), and if possible how this may have caused the unwanted behaviour you experienced.